# How can I attach a function to JQuery's find() function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, find, anonymous-function

I have an Array of elements I wish to search for a class within. Once found I then want to attach a function so I can manipulate child elements. My research has led me to the each loop and the find function. I want to do something like this:

```
$(arrayOfElems).each(function( i ) {
    $(this).find('.something').function() {
        console.log('found element: '+$(this));
    }
}
```

Excuse the bad code!

Comment: can you just send the markup

Comment: If your search lead to jQuery's `each`, why aren't you using it

Comment: Where does `arrayOfElems` come from? Is it what it sounds like? Will those elements have the `something` class, only *children* of them, or only *descendants* of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use .each function https://api.jquery.com/each/

```
$(this).find('.something').each(function( index ) {
  console.log( index + ": " + $( this ).text() );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how your code is structured you may need an additional loop.

```
   $("ul.StuffToloop").each(function (i, item) {
                if (item.classList == "ClassToDoThings") {//first check your array of elements
                   $( item).append( "<p>Test</p>" );//if matched add your function that does things to child elements
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(arrayOfElems).each(function( i ) {
    ManipulateItem($(this).find('.something'));
 }

 function ManipulateItem(item){
       //do stuff
 }
```